# How to align uielement textbox above a line made using lineseries

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJs and I'm adding a UIElement textbox I would like to place this above the lineseries but when I give the scale of the lineseries to the addUIElement it does not show up.

```
chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox,myseries.scale).setText('test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a scale of another series, then the positioning for the UIElement is done using the coordinates of the series. By default the UIElement will be positioned to 0,0 coordinate. If your line series doesn't show this coordinate then the UIElement will be out of view.

So if you have a line from 10,10 to 20,20 and you don't set the position of the UIElement, then you most likely will not see the UIElement as it's positioned to 0,0 position. You should in that case set the position of the UIElement to something in the range of 10,10-20,20. [`uiElement.setPosition({x: 12, y:12 })`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/interfaces/uielement.html#setposition)

See the code snippet below for a working example.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    UIElementBuilders
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const series = chart.addLineSeries()

series.addArrayY([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1])

// add text box on the chart, using series scale
const textOverLine = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, series.scale)
    .setText('My Text')
    // position the text, this is in the line series coordinates
    .setPosition({ x: 4.5, y: 2.1 })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```